How do I fix my issue of having held broken packages and adding libGL.so.1?
I am trying to fix my held broken packages issue, I am missing libGL.so.1 and am trying to download steam to get the sims 4. I cannot download EA app on my system because EA only runs on windows and mac, I obviously have Debian 10/linux 10. How do I fix my issue of having held broken packages and adding libGL.so.1? Below is what I am receiving
The following packages have unmet dependencies: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libzstd1:i386 (>= 1.3.2) but it is not going to be installed E: unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. 

you are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and steam may not run: libGL.so.1

Fatal error: Failed to load steamui.so


https://endoflife.date/debian First things first, upgrade to a supported release. That alone likely will solve the issue.

@ChanganAuto how do you upgrade to debian 12?

The Debian Upgrade suggests some methods. And having a current backup of all your personal data, a fresh installation is always an option and often takes less time and gives better results.

@TianaTrammell  Seeing as I was helping you over in a Ubuntu chat room, I'd be happy to continue helping.  Knowing from that chat that your computer has no CD/DVD ROM, or a USB port, the only option you have is to upgrade from 10 to 11, get the graphics working in 11 again and then upgrade to 12.  We may be able to skip that if you can download and install netboot.xyz to the EFI partition and then boot it using your firmware's boot selection menu.
